# How do I apply a symbol as a function in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Is there a way I can apply '+ to '( 1 2 3)?

edit: what i am trying to say is that the function i get will be a symbol. Is there a way to apply that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(apply (eval '+) '(1 2 3))
```

Should do it.

Comment: I got an error " compile: unbound identifier (and no #%top syntax transformer is bound) in: +"

Comment: what version of scheme? I tested that in Dr. Scheme before posting

Comment: This is interesting. the statement by itself will not compile. It needs to be within a function or can be evaluated in the REPL.Are there restrictions to the binding regarding eval?

Comment: Eval checks for an a symbol in a certain environment. Using the repl it might work but within a different environment or in newer scheme, it's possible that the eval default to an empty env if none is passed.

Answer (score 4):

In R5RS you need

```
(apply (eval '+ (scheme-report-environment 5)) '(1 2 3))
```

The "Pretty Big" language in Dr. Scheme allows for:

```
(apply (eval '+) '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about 'apply'? Use the variable + instead of the symbol + .

```
(apply + '(1 2 3))
```

[R5RS](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_556)

Comment: The OP specifically wants to know how to convert a symbol into a procedure. Simply using + instead of '+ does not answer the question.

Comment: @mgadda: as you can see, he was adding that requirement later.

Comment: Except not. The original unedited question refers to the symbol '+. The edit just reiterates that it's a symbol and provides no modifications to the original question.

Comment: @mgadda: it's a typical beginner problem to use symbols instead of functions. Even if he had a symbol in the original question, it could well be that he does not understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```
;; This works the same as funcall in Common Lisp:
(define (funcall fun . args)
  (apply fun args))

(funcall + 1 2 3 4) => 10
(funcall (lambda (a b) (+ a b) 2 3) => 5
(funcall newline) => *prints newline*
(apply newline) => *ERROR*
(apply newline '()) => *prints newline*
```

Btw, what's the deal with this "syntax highlighting" ??

Answer (score 1):

In Racket's scheme it would be

```
#lang scheme

(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(apply (eval '+ ns) '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score -1):

How about the scheme "apply"

```
(apply + `(1 2 3)) => 6
```

I hope that was what you were asking :)

Comment: Hi the thing is + is in terms of a symbol '+ and not a procedure. Apply does not work.